# fan is working always in Asus X542U

Tags: fedora, fan, sensors, asus

I installed Fedora 29 to Asus X542U. Now fan is working always and I can not control it. I tried `sudo modprobe asus_laptop` command but result is:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'asus_laptop': No such device
```

also I typed

```
dmesg | grep asus
```

result is

```
[    5.353567] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
[    5.358125] asus_wmi: Initialization: 0x1
[    5.358180] asus_wmi: BIOS WMI version: 9.0
[    5.358216] asus_wmi: SFUN value: 0x21
[    5.359322] input: Asus WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input20
[    5.359947] asus_wmi: Number of fans: 0
[ 9813.808938] asus_wmi: Unknown key cf pressed
```

You can see `asus_wmi: Number of fans: 0`.

also I checked `fancontrol` service

```
➜  ~ fancontrol
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Error: Can't read configuration file

➜  ~ systemctl status fancontrol         
● fancontrol.service - Start fan control, if configured
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service; disabled; vendor>
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I started `fancontrol` service with this command: `systemctl start fancontrol`

but again it is not working

```
➜  ~ systemctl status fancontrol
● fancontrol.service - Start fan control, if configured
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

there is no fan info in output of `sensors` command

```
➜  ~ sensors
ath10k_hwmon-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +91.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

What should I do ?

my system :

```
➜  ~ inxi -Fxxx 
System:    Host: localhost.localdomain Kernel: 4.19.5-300.fc29.x86_64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 8.2.1 
           Desktop: Gnome 3.30.2 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM 3.30.1 Distro: Fedora release 29 (Twenty Nine) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: X542URR v: 1.0 serial: <root required> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X542URR v: 1.0 serial: <root required> UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends 
           v: X542URR.303 date: 12/04/2017 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 35.8 Wh condition: 35.8/38.0 Wh (94%) volts: 7.6/7.6 model: ASUSTeK ASUS Battery 
           type: Li-ion serial:   status: Not charging cycles: 8 
           Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech K520 serial: 2011-1b-bd-5d-c3 
           charge: 70% (should be ignored) rechargeable: yes status: Discharging 
           Device-2: hidpp_battery_1 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse serial: 4055-57-b5-45-59 
           charge: 55% (should be ignored) rechargeable: yes status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-8550U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake rev: A 
           L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 31872 
           Speed: 1450 MHz min/max: 400/1800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1450 2: 1380 3: 1464 4: 1564 5: 1567 
           6: 1499 7: 1450 8: 1390 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           chip ID: 8086:5917 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 930MX] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia v: 410.78 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           chip ID: 10de:134e 
           Display: x11 server: Fedora Project X.org 1.20.3 driver: nvidia compositor: gnome-shell 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce 930MX/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 410.78 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:9d71 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.19.5-300.fc29.x86_64 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 
           v: kernel port: d000 bus ID: 02:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 4c:ed:fb:0b:4e:84 
           Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter vendor: AzureWave 
           driver: ath10k_pci v: kernel port: d000 bus ID: 03:00.0 chip ID: 168c:0042 
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: 80:c5:f2:79:4a:4b 
           IF-ID-1: virbr0 state: down mac: 52:54:00:81:88:26 
           IF-ID-2: virbr0-nic state: down mac: 52:54:00:81:88:26 
           IF-ID-3: vmnet1 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: 00:50:56:c0:00:01 
           IF-ID-4: vmnet8 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: 00:50:56:c0:00:08 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 2.26 TiB used: 1.24 TiB (54.8%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: Q300. size: 447.13 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s serial: 97KB50IPKQ4U 
           rev: 12.3 scheme: MBR 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS541010B7E610 size: 931.51 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s 
           rotation: 5400 rpm serial: WXW1E87AVA83 rev: 1A03 scheme: GPT 
           ID-3: /dev/sdc type: USB vendor: Toshiba model: MQ01ABD100 size: 931.51 GiB serial: 20171212 
           scheme: MBR 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 48.97 GiB used: 20.13 GiB (41.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-0 
           ID-2: /boot size: 975.9 MiB used: 183.5 MiB (18.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
           ID-3: /home size: 381.23 GiB used: 32.14 GiB (8.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-2 
           ID-4: swap-1 size: 7.80 GiB used: 728.2 MiB (9.1%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-1 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 44.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 43 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 320 Uptime: 5h 47m Memory: 7.67 GiB used: 4.56 GiB (59.5%) Init: systemd v: 239 
           runlevel: 5 target: graphical.target Compilers: gcc: 8.2.1 Shell: zsh v: 5.6.2 
           running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.26
```

---

I created a ticket in redhat [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1663927)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the system BIOS for settings relating to fan control? I had a similar issue on an HP laptop and managed to sort it out from there.

Comment: i checked BIOS but i can not find any settings related to fan control. itshows only fan rpm info. i think problem is fancontrol service of linux